# Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource" exception

Tags: c#, .net, dll, rabbitmq, paket

I have an application that uses **RabbitMQ.Client** library. This library has a dependency on **Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource** (v1.1.28) library.
Now, I have Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource library with v2.0.1 in my project. So I get an error whenever RabbitMq.Client tries to load this dependent assembly:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource, Version=1.1.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have tried using **bindingRedirect** to resolve this but it is not working. I also can't directly NuGet this library because we use "paket" to download all the dependencies needed for the application and it already contains:

> nuget Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource 1.1.28.0

Following is the content in my "paket.lock" file:

```
    RabbitMQ.Client (5.1)
      Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist (>= 1.1.28)
    Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource (1.1.28)
      Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister (>= 1.1.28)
      Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist (>= 1.1.28)
    Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist (2.0.1)
```

Could anyone please suggest any idea on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: .NET Core or .NET Framework? In your project, you can try to downgrade to "1.1.28".

Comment: Try using the latest version of RabbitMq.Client.. i think it is 6.1